# Using Kelvin transform to solve Dirichlet problem for Laplace's equation

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, laplacian, linear-pde

Let $u$ be a $C^{2}$ -solution of
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta u=0 & \text { in } \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash B_{R} \\
u=0 & \text { on } \partial B_{R}
\end{aligned}
$$
Prove that $u \equiv 0$ if
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\lim _{|x| \rightarrow \infty} \frac{u(x)}{\ln |x|}=0 & \text { for } n=2, \\
\lim _{|x| \rightarrow \infty} u(x)=0 & \text { for } n \geq 3
\end{array}
$$

I've tried to use Kelvin's transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_transform in order to get compect domain. Will it allow me to use the Mean Value theorem? Maximum principle?